# Find currently playing song on Wear os

Tags: android, wear-os, android-jetpack

Is there a way to get the currently playing song on jetpack compose for wear os?

I tried to use MediaSessionService but I am getting
java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to control media.
is there a better way? or a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

MediaSessionService generally requires a token from the notification.

On mobile it's possible, as https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/media-controller-test demonstrates.

**I don't believe this is possible on Wear**, because you can't grant the notification permission, but you could try the same approaches to confirm this.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller/blob/238521ed1bcd37cea7aee20a35072827e9003ea2/mediacontroller/src/main/java/com/example/android/mediacontroller/tasks/FindMediaSessionAppsTask.kt#L41

```
    override val mediaApps: List<MediaAppDetails>
        get() = MediaAppControllerUtils.getMediaAppsFromControllers(
                mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(listenerComponent),
                packageManager,
                resources
        )
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller/blob/238521ed1bcd37cea7aee20a35072827e9003ea2/mediacontroller/src/main/java/com/example/android/mediacontroller/NotificationListener.java#L30

```
    // Helper method to check if our notification listener is enabled. In order to get active media
    // sessions, we need an enabled notification listener component.
    public static boolean isEnabled(Context context) {
        return NotificationManagerCompat
                .getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
                .contains(context.getPackageName());
```